# How to rename files with a backslash in its name?

Tags: bash, terminal, rename, batch-rename

I have a bunch of files with this pattern:

`string1\string2-string3.txt`

Trying to remove this part from names, `string1\string2`, in Linux terminal using `rename`, but can't figure out how to detect the backslash in its name?

These were my attempts:

`$ find -name "string1\string2*" -type f | rename 's/string1\string2//g'`

`$ find -name "string1\\string2*" -type f | rename 's/string1\\string2//g'`

`$ find -name "string1"\"string2*" -type f | rename 's/string1"\"string2//g'`

But these attempts did not work, so, how can I do this?

Comment: Where do you get `rename` that works like `sed`? Can you link the documentation?

Comment: its documentation in `man rename`, I guess.

Comment: My `man rename` says nothing remotely similar. Nor does anything I can [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) [online](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename). Do you have a link I can look at?

Comment: Ah, found it. It's a perl script. Called perl-rename on my system but rename on Ubuntu and such.

Comment: Single quotes are easier. `find -name 'string1\\string2*' | perl-rename 's/string1\\string2//g'`, works for me.

Comment: yes, great! that's it! it works! :)

Comment: Thank you @n.m. ! 
You can write it as an answer to let me choose it as the right answer, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

To detect them, use 3 backslashes ..

```
find . -name "hello\\\file*" -type f
./hello\file2
./hello\file3
./hello\file1
```

Seems to work fine for me.